# Is there a way to revoke another user's access tokens and end their session in Identity Server 4?

Tags: access-token, openid-connect, identityserver4

Is there a recommended way to revoke another user's access in Identity Server 4?  The use case I'm looking at is an Administrator revoking system access for a currently logged in user.

I've read the documentation for the [Revocation Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/revocation.html) and can see how that can be used by a user to revoke their own access. But how can this be done when the Administrator wouldn't know what a particular user's access token is?

Same goes for the [End Session Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/endsession.html) I suppose, how would the Admin know their ID Token?

What I've tried so far is implementing an `IProfileService` and checking the user's account is valid in the `IsActiveAsync` method. In our customer db I can deactivate their account and this has the desired effect of redirecting them to to the Login page. But the tokens and session are still 'alive'. Would this be a good place to end session and revoke access token?

Or is persisting user tokens to the database an option?

**Update**

Based on the answer from @Mashton below I found an example of how to implement persistence in the Identity Server docs [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html).

Creating the data migrations described there will persist tokens to `[dbo].[PersistedGrants]` in the `Key` column. I was confused at first since they didn't look anything like my reference access tokens but after a little digging I found that they are stored as a SHA-256 hash. Looking at the `DefaultGrantStore` implementation in [Identity Server's GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/295026919db5bec1b0c8f36fc89e8aeb4b5a0e3f/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/Default/DefaultGrantStore.cs) the Hashed Key is calculated as follows ...

```
    const string KeySeparator = ":";
    protected string GetHashedKey(string value)
    {
        return (value + KeySeparator + _grantType).Sha256();
    }
```

... where the `value` is the token and the `_grantType` is one of the following ...

```
    public static class PersistedGrantTypes
    {
        public const string AuthorizationCode = "authorization_code";
        public const string ReferenceToken = "reference_token";
        public const string RefreshToken = "refresh_token";
        public const string UserConsent = "user_consent";
    }
```

Using persisted grants doesn't give me the original access token but it does allow me the ability to revoke access tokens since the `[dbo].[PersistedGrants]` table has the `SubjectId`.

**Update 2 - Identity Server keeps creating tokens**

I created an implicit mvc client and after successful login I'm dumpimg the claims on the screen. I delete the access token from the persisted grant db then use Postman to end the session in the End Session Endpoint (using the id token in the claims). When I refresh the browser I'd expect the user to get redirected to the login screen *but instead* they get a new access token and a new id token. The `Client.IdentityTokenLifetime` is only 30 seconds.

Any ideas of what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only revoke `Reference tokens` not `JWTs`, and yes those need to be stored in a db. Have a look at the `IPersistedGrantStore` (of the top of my head, so may have got the name wrong), and you'll see the structure is pretty simple.

Once you've got them stored, you can obviously do anything you like admin-wise, such as change the expiry or just outright delete them.

Comment: Thanks @Mashton. Persisting to the db solved half the problem i.e. deleting the access token. I can't see the id token being persisted anywhere though so technically a new access token could be automatically created. Do you know how to remove their session?

Comment: @GavinSutherland I thought that reference tokens were just a unique identifier that was sent to a Protected Resource, the resource then sent reference token to the STS (idsrv) to materialize into a full token after validation that the reference token was not revoked. So the actual tokens are not seen by user. I am not an expert on these matters though. See https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/

Comment: Hi @Mardoxx. A relying party (e.g. mvc site) would have to send a reference token to Identity Server introspection endpoint in order to get user claims. Self contained tokens would not need to do this. This post is about revoking a user's access and not about getting claims.

Comment: You revoke reference token, user can no longer do anything, surely? @GavinSutherland

Comment: When I remove the access token Identity Server just creates a new one

Comment: Something doesn't sound right there. We use the `ResourceOwnerPassword` grant, and a request for an access token from the IdSvr results in the storage of a grant in the db, and a `Reference token` being returned to the client. Now whenever the client tries to access protected resources, using that reference token, the protected resource will call into IdSvr to validate the reference is for a token that exists, hasn't expired, has appropriate grants etc. If I remove that grant from the db then all calls using that reference token will return a 401, and the user will need to request a new token.

Comment: Hi @Mashton. If I try to use the access token that has been deleted then yes access is denied to the resource. However, Identity Server is automatically creating a new tokens when an authenticated user refreshes their browser.

Comment: I think I'd describe that as the client is re-requesting an access token, rather than the IdSvr automatically creating a new token. IdSvr won't create the tokens unless your client provides the credentials. I'd look into what mechanism I was using to request tokens, and go from there. Are cookies/session involved somewhere?

Comment: @Mashton. Yeah you're right. I'm using OWIN cookie authentication on the MVC side. In the `OnValidateIdentity` event handler I was calling the token introspection endpoint and rejecting the identity on receiving an inactive token whereas I think I should probably call end session (as well as reject identity?!). I'll add an update above later today. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GavinSutherland did you made this implemented? do you mind posting the update

Comment: Hi @Jay. I'll try and post an update soon. In short were are persisting the tokens to the db. On every request to the website we use the introspection endpoint to validate if the token is still valid. If it's not valid (which includes it not existing) then we are signing the user out of both the websites session AND the identity provider session.

Comment: found another approach using user security stamp update upon every login process, so authorize/token end points will see if there is any change, then take the user to login process, this way user will only have one active session every time, and if admin wants to take a control then do update the security stamp of the user with the change works perfect, short lived access token and this combination spot on.

Comment: If user is logged-in on 3 different browser (1, 2, 3), when user trying login on 4th browser. then I want to kill 1st session. so that when user try to access any secure resource on 1st browser, then user should redirect to login. Any suggestions for this scenario. I have stored the session id in db to track the session.

Comment: @Ravi if you have implemented your own `IPersistedGrantStore` then you are in control of the logic for storing/retrieving/manipulating the reference tokens. We had a similar requirement (with logging in a second time revoking any existing tokens) and put this logic into the `IPersistedGrantStore` to make all existing tokens (of the same type) invalid for the user requesting a new token. It sounds like your use-case is similar, but with just a bit more custom logic needed.

Comment: @Mashton, implementing your own IPersistedGrantStore means Extend the PersistedGrand table with additional fields. Right? Also I tried the reference token, if remove or invalidate the entry then all tokens are become invalid and client app redirect to login page but "main IS4 application is still not logged-out and it may be because it's using cookie based authentication".